# Why does didUpdateLocation value differ from "my location" on map?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I'm getting a user's location over time and continuously overlaying this information on an `MKMapView`.

My problem is, the location isn't correct. Hear me out. `MKMapView`'s blue dot for my current location is showing my location EXACTLY correct. Correct as could be. However, my location from `didUpdateLocations` is not this same location. It's showing up ~500 meters WNW. I'm storing locations as `CLLocation` and displaying them using their `coordinate` member.

I can walk around and it will show my path very precisely, but offset 500m WNW. Why is this happening? How do I get my current location without this offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that the problem is China's cartography. This is well-documented:

[All Maps In China Are Wrong](https://jpgamboa.com/all-maps-in-china-are-wrong/)

[What The Map?](https://polastre.com/2013/02/what-the-map/)

[A Solution (too complicated in my opinion)](http://www.sinosplice.com/life/archives/2013/07/16/a-more-complete-ios-solution-to-the-china-gps-offset-problem)

...so.... what next?

I'm going to use Chinese map providers' APIs to provide a simpler solution (Autonavi, Baidu, etc)